# Add more "depth" starting with one texture

Tags: texturing, materials, photorealism, pbr, depth-map

I am using the Node Wrangler to apply the texture (I am using just one texture, a simple photo) to simulate roughness, normals and so on.

[image]

Is there a way to create more "depth" starting from just a texture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take another *Image Texture Node*, open the same texture, and set the *Color Space* to *Non-Color* and use that to simulate depth using a *Bump Node*. It usually works, sometimes doesn't, so this isn't a surefire way to work about it. But that's what I would do if I was restricted to just that texture.